# Using CORS filter for SOAP service

Tags: java, soap, cors

I have been working with Enterprise application which expose soap and restful webservice. I have used Restful webservice with cross domain calls in implementing CORS filter in my web.xml. Now am trying to work with SOAP service(where my ajax call to soap occurs). How can i configure CORS filter here to access in cross domain

Adding Snippet

Since Rest implementation is servlet mapping i have my servlet mappings like this

```
<servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
<init-param>
<param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
<param-value>com.servicedata.service</param-value>
</init-param>
</servlet>


<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I have deployed my application in a application server,
My Applciation.xml looks like this

```
<module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>UI.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>Web</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>Router.war</web-uri>
      <context-root>Router</context-root>
    </web>
```

So it will be exposed at `http:<hostname>:<port>/Router/services/myservice/123`
I can hit this URL with restclient and i got a response for this. 
when am making an ajax call, my application is not allowing to access my service.[Authentication Denied]

so i added a CORS filter for this

```
class ResponseFilter{
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

In Web.xml

```
<filter>
<filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
<filter-class>com.servlet.ResponseFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

It works for Rest,this is fine. In case of SOAP

My soap URL would be      `http:<hostname>:<port>/Business/service/Manager`

This is URL will be defined in my wsdl.

So when i try to access my SOAP deployed in my application it doesn't allow to access.Here cross origin is not allowed because i have ajax call from local server.localhost to hostserver

I have configured CORS for Rest since it is servlet mapping. How can i do for SOAP services.

Comment: "The same way". I take it that you tried and you got problems, so if you want help with that you will need to post specifics. Error, configuration, the javascript code which does the SOAP call, the works.

Comment: Gimby I have added the snippet of my code

Answer (score 1):

1) create "handler.xml" and put these lines of your handler class.

```
<javaee:handler-chains xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <javaee:handler-chain>
        <javaee:handler>
            <javaee:handler-class>somepackage.MySOAPHandler</javaee:handler-class>
        </javaee:handler>
    </javaee:handler-chain>
</javaee:handler-chains>
```

2) Create SOAPHandler class in your "somepackage" package.

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage;
import javax.xml.transform.Source;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.MessageContext;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPHandler;
import javax.xml.ws.handler.soap.SOAPMessageContext;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

public class MySOAPHandler implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext> {
    Logger logger;

    public MySOAPHandler() {
        super();
        logger = Logger.getLogger(MySOAPHandler.class);
    }

    @Override
    public void close(MessageContext arg0) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleFault(SOAPMessageContext arg0) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(SOAPMessageContext smc) {
        System.out.println("Handling soap message...");

        Map<String, List<String>> map = (Map<String, List<String>>)smc.get(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS);        
        Boolean outboundProperty = (Boolean) smc
                .get(MessageContext.MESSAGE_OUTBOUND_PROPERTY);

        if (outboundProperty.booleanValue()) {
            logger.debug("\nOutbound message:");
              //this is underlying http response object
              HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) smc.get(MessageContext.SERVLET_RESPONSE);

                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "false");
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
                response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
                response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Accept, x-requested-with, Content-Type, SOAPAction, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Response-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin");
        } else {
            logger.debug("\nInbound message:");
        }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<QName> getHeaders() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

3) Add an annotation for your WebServiceProvider

```
@ServiceMode(value = javax.xml.ws.Service.Mode.MESSAGE)
@HandlerChain(file="handler.xml")
@WebServiceProvider(serviceName = "MyWS", portName = "MyWSPort", targetNamespace = "http://namespace = "WEB-INF/wsdl/MyWSDL.wsdl")
public class MyWS implements javax.xml.ws.Provider<SOAPMessage> {

   ...
}
```

It will work then.